# Compare two csv files and output a third csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to read two csv files with different lengths. My first file is a reference file that contains time stamp data as shown below all the way through to 23:59:58

Some sample data for the reference file to represent the problem is shown below

```
2021-04-04 00:00:00 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:01 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:02 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:03 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:04 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:05 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:06 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:07 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:08 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:09 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:10 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:11 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:12 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:13 ,-1.0
```

My second file is the original file that can be found here

Some sample data for the original file to represent the problem is shown below

```
HEADER_TIME_STAMP, UNIT
2021-04-04 00:00:00.005 ,0.4
2021-04-04 00:00:01.005 ,0.3
2021-04-04 00:00:02.005 ,0.2
2021-04-04 00:00:03.005 ,0.3
2021-04-04 00:00:04.005 ,0.4
2021-04-04 00:00:05.005 ,0.5
2021-04-04 00:00:10.005 ,0.4
2021-04-04 00:00:11.005 ,0.2
2021-04-04 00:00:12.005 ,0.3
2021-04-04 00:00:13.005 ,0.1
```

It has missing time stamps when compared to the reference file.  When the original file has a missing time stamp I need to add the line from the reference file into a third csv file. If the time stamp is not missing it must add the line from the original file.

Comparisons to see if a line is the same should be done using only the time stamp in the HH:MM:SS format ignoring the milliseconds.

I have tried the following code that is able to do most of what I want it to do, however it is unable to stop iterating through the original file when adding lines from the reference file to make p for missing lines. Thus leading to the program also ignoring some lines that are present in the original file.

```
# compare the difference between two given csv and produce a third csv that contains all possible time stamps
def csv_compare_new(c_o, c_r):
    with open(c_o, "r") as original, open(c_r, "r") as reference:
        original_reader = csv.reader(original, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        reference_reader = csv.reader(reference, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

        with open('compare.csv', 'w') as out:
            new_writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            print(new_writer.dialect)
            for line_or, line_ref in itertools.zip_longest(original_reader, reference_reader):
                if line_or is None:
                    new_writer.writerow(line_ref)
                else:
                    if line_ref[0][0:19] in line_or[0][0:19]:
                        new_writer.writerow(line_or)
                    else:
                        if line_ref[0][0:19] not in line_or[0][0:19]:
                            new_writer.writerow(line_ref)
            out.close()
```

I hope someone could help solve the bug that I am getting. Note that I would like it to remain as python code and preferably a memory efficient solution.

The desired outcome for the sample data is as follows

```
2021-04-04 00:00:00.005 ,0.4
2021-04-04 00:00:01.005 ,0.3
2021-04-04 00:00:02.005 ,0.2
2021-04-04 00:00:03.005 ,0.3
2021-04-04 00:00:04.005 ,0.4
2021-04-04 00:00:05.005 ,0.5
2021-04-04 00:00:06 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:07 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:08 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:09 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:10.005 ,0.4
2021-04-04 00:00:11.005 ,0.2
2021-04-04 00:00:12.005 ,0.3
2021-04-04 00:00:13.005 ,0.1
```

However it is not adding the lines from the original file as expected, instead adds the lines from the reference file as shown below.

```
2021-04-04 00:00:00.005 ,0.4
2021-04-04 00:00:01.005 ,0.3
2021-04-04 00:00:02.005,0.2
2021-04-04 00:00:03.005 ,0.3
2021-04-04 00:00:04.005 ,0.4
2021-04-04 00:00:05.005 ,0.5
2021-04-04 00:00:06 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:07 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:08 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:09 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:10 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:11 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:12 ,-1.0
2021-04-04 00:00:13 ,-1.0
```

Comment: In the documentation, the file is always opened setting `newline` for example `with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:` - was there a reason you don't do the same? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv - the doc says: 

    If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.

Comment: Please include some minimal sample data (i.e. as little as possible, just enough to show the problem, and no more) for both files in the question __as text__ - i.e. NOT as a link or picture. Remove unneeded columns when this doesn't affect the problem; if removing columns does affect the problem, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: No there is no reason as to why I did not do the same. Simply an oversight I shall add that to my code, thank you for catching the error.

Comment: You're zipping the files together to iterate over them; that means you can't skip forward on one file or the other. That would account for "unable to stop iterating through the original file when adding lines from the reference file" and "ignoring some lines that are present in the original" - so you'll have to __not__ zip them and instead iterate on them independently.

Comment: I have edited the post to better explain my problem and added some sample data as text. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to achieve this

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('reference.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('original.csv')


# Concatenate, making sure the df that needs to be updated is first in the list
df = pd.concat([df2,df1])

# This will drop the milliseconds
df['t'] = df['HEADER_TIME_STAMP'].astype('datetime64[s]')

# Droping duplicates on the new time column
# This will keep the first duplicated record and drop the second
df.drop_duplicates(subset='t').sort_values(by='HEADER_TIME_STAMP').drop(columns='t').to_csv('combined.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It did solve the problem however the time stamps aren't in the right order is there any where that they could be sorted in ascending order. It is for this reason that I hesitated exploring a pandas option.

Comment: @Dhivas Updated the answer to have the sort